# Variadic templates, compiler apologies

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I had asked the similar question before , understood that i can make it work by partially specialization. But to understand variadic templates basics i modified the code such like this.

```
template<typename T, typename... args>
struct counter{
static const int value= 1+ counter<args...>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct counter<T>{
static const int value = 0;
};
```

**error** : "sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'args ...' into a fixed-length argument list"

i understand this is bug and has been fixed in gcc 4.7.0

so to fix all this we have to use trick or whatever , which is partial specializing the template.

```
template<typename... Args> struct counter;

template<>
struct counter<> {
static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct counter<T, Args...> {
static const int value = 1 + counter<Args...>::value;
};
```

**Actual question**: so I really want to know what special effect does partial specialization does here so that code works or I should ask how partial specialization resolves the issue? (why is it second version doesn't hits the bug? ). Any explanation with motivation problem and examples will be very helpful.

Comment: please don't tell me to use `sizeof...(args)`

Comment: +1: "compiler apologies"... don't see that everyday.

Comment: Wait, why is the second version a "trick"? The first version uses partial specialization just as much. And arguably the second version is far cleaner and more powerful, so that I would never have considered the fist version to begin with.

Comment: The first version cannot accept 0 arguments (and reports 1 less than it should).

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: "please don't tell me to use sizeof...(args)" Why not? That's how you're supposed to get the argument count.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Because getting the argument count is almost certainly a minimal reproducible example, not the full design.  And `sizeof... (args)` can't replace whatever the full design is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version avoids the bug because the primary template is declared as `template<typename...>`, i.e. it's variadic. The key to the bug is in the error message: "sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'args ...' into a **fixed-length** argument list" (emphasis mine).

Thus `counter<Args...>::value` will work on that second case because `counter` is tailored to accept *any* number of arguments. However, in the first case where the primary template is declared as `template<typename T, typename... args>`, the compiler has to separate `args` into a **fixed-length** part (`T`) and a variadic part (the new `args`). Presumably that's the very functionality that is not implemented in your version of GCC.

I have no reason to believe that whatever machinery allows the `<T, Args...>` specialization of the second case to match the `<typename...>` primary template could be reused for fixed-length expansion.

(Finally since the support of C++11 features is marked as 'experimental' by GCC you really can't have any expectation as to what will work and what won't, much less *why* and *how*. Those kind of questions can only reasonably be answered by GCC developers on their mailing-list, not us. We're not mind readers.)

Answer (score -1):

The code that's special is the first case.  It happens to hit a particular compiler bug.

Comment: and why is it second version doesn't hits the bug? it's what i want to know

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The bug is very narrow.  100% of test cases the developers tried don't hit the bug, or they would have had it fixed before you ever saw it.  Hitting a bug is a rare event, avoiding the bug is extremely common.  And which code hits a bug or not tells you nothing about the code, only about the bug.  There's nothing interesting here, unless you were trying to either fix the bug, or blame crash reports on a now-fixed bug.